# Loading data into UICollectionView bunch by bunch

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am building an chat app and I have a problem with the collection view. In my app I just want to do something like whatsapp, in starting I load the first 50 messages and when we scroll down then want to fetch other messages bunch by bunch. But when I doing this and call the collection view reloadData method then it scroll to the top message. And I don't want they scrolling. Can you help me. Please..

I just simply want to make the collectionView similar to whatsapp's chat view.. i.e. load more messages when user scroll to the older messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is just feeding (inserting) cell into collection view without reloading it.

Check this [appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618097-insertitems), on inserting item.

determine the new indexPaths and then feed it to collection view using following

```
yourCollectionView.insertItems(at indexPaths: newIndexPaths)
```

Comment: No , the case is that , I load first 50 messages in collection view. And now want to load older messages when user scrolling down.

Comment: The approach is correct @DeepakKharpodiya as you can insert the new data into items 50-99. I would also recommend to not load once you've reached the bottom but to grab more items once you're like 50 items from the bottom so it usually never looks like it's loading.

Answer (score 1):

Detect when you reach at the end and fetch more data

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
    let lastSectionIndex = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
    let lastRowIndex = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
    if indexPath.section == lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex 
    {
        //fetch more items
        //add items to data array
        //Reload collectionview
    }
}
```

Comment: @DeepakKharpodiya whats the problem?

Comment: in this case it will goes under a infinity loop and crash at the end. because when the collection view is open the it auto scroll to the last index and then scroll down to the older messages

Comment: @DeepakKharpodiya In this case you have to maintain `total` count and check if `data array` count is less than `total` count then only fetch new items..

Comment: @DeepakKharpodiya see initially set `total = 50` then lets say you are fetching 10 items each time, then after every fetch, you have to check `if(dataArray.count < total)` if its true then only you have to fetch new items..it still its not helping you share your code

Answer (score 0):

Try `pagination` concept

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row + 1 == dataArray.count && dataArray.count < completeData.count {
        fetchMoreData()
    }
    .....
}

func fetchMoreData() {

    //Fetch and add more data to your dataArray.
    //Reload collectionView
}
```

Comment: in this case it will goes under a infinity loop and crash at the end. because when the collection view is open the it auto scroll to the last index and then scroll down to the older messages

Comment: Sateesh in all case I will found the if condition true because when my collection view is appear I scroll it to the bottom... Similar to any messaging app. And then scroll down for  older messages. So in that case every time this condition is true.